# Wrap all words between specific characters

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have some text in different elements. What I want is wrap all words between the specific character / in a span element. See example below.

```
<ul>
<li>/Lorem Ipsum/ has been the industry's standard.</li>
<li>With desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of /Lorem Ipsum../</li>
<li>There are /many/ variations of passages of /Lorem/ Ipsum available, but the..</li>
</ul>
```

I was wondering of this possible. Because as far I know you can only take one word per element. For example, this element has two words between /.

```
<li>There are /many/ variations of passages of /Lorem/ Ipsum available, but the..</li>
```

Should be

```
<ul>
<li><span class="wrapped">Lorem Ipsum</span> has been the industry's standard.</li>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regex `/\/(.*?)\//g` with `html()` accepting callback function.

The regex will match the string surrounded by slashes. `(.*?)` will add the string inside slashes into first captured group which can be used in replacement part.

**Note:** I assumed there is no nested HTML elements inside `li`.

```js
$('ul li').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\/(.*?)\//g, '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span.highlighted {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>/Lorem Ipsum/ has been the industry's standard.</li>
  <li>With desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of /Lorem Ipsum../</li>
  <li>There are /many/ variations of passages of /Lorem/ Ipsum available, but the..</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfect @Tushar, thank you! Small question: What does `$1` mean? Between the `span` tag? I try to learn it.

Comment: @Appel It's first captured group value. In this case the string between `/` and `/`. Anything that matches in the parenthesis is added in captured group `\/(something)\/` For this example `$1` will be `something`.